# ¿Cómo atraer un nodo dentro de otro nodo?

Tags: ios, swift, spritekit

Estoy tratando de hacer un juego como este con Spritekit https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OzJ0.jpg donde se arrastra un Sknode a un "contenedor" si coinciden con el Sknode debe ponerse en su contenedor, ¿Cómo podría lograrlo? en este momento lo que puedo hacer es mover el nodo por la pantalla (el cuadrado amarillo), pero no logro que se quede en la posición (el cuadrado gris) que le corresponde como en la imagen, https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLAfx.jpg para una mejor referencia, me gustaría que fuese algo así como este video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ulB49kAIK1o cualquier ayuda sería genial!

Answer (score 0):

Hay distintas formas de hacerlo. La idea principal es añadir un objeto de UIPanGestireRecognizer a la vista de la escena. Supongamos que el nodo que quieres mover y el contenedor son instancias de SKSpriteNode que se llaman nodo y contenedor. Añade este código dentro de la clase que controla la escena:

```
let gestoDeslizar = UIPanGestureRecognizer()
```

Luego crea esta función en la misma clase:

```
var nodoTocado = false

@objc func controladorGestoDeslizar(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
  switch sender.state {
    case .began:
      // Comprobar si el toque está dentro del objeto que quieres que se mueva
      var touchLocation = recognizer.location(in: recognizer.view)
      touchLocation = self.convertPoint(fromView: touchLocation)
      // Comprobamos si el el usuario ha tocado el nodo
      if nodo.contains(touchLocation) {
        nodoTocado = true
      }
    case .moved:
     if nodoTocado {
      // Cambiar la posición del objeto a la posición actual del toque
      let traslacion = recognizer.translation(in: recognizer.view)
      nodo.position += traslacion
      recognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), in: recognizer.view)
     }
    case .ended:
     if nodoTocado {
      // Comprobar si el objeto está dentro del contenedor y mover el objeto para centrarlo
      var touchLocation = recognizer.location(in: recognizer.view)
      touchLocation = self.convertPoint(fromView: touchLocation)
      if contenedor.contains(touchLocation) {
        let terminarMovimiento = SKAction.move(to: contenedor.position, interval: /*Pon el tiempo que quieras*/)
        nodo.run(terminarMovimiento)
      } else {
        // Devuelve el nodo a la posición inicial
      }
      nodoTocado = false
     }
  }
}
```

Esta función va a hacer posible mover el objeto a los contenedores. Ahora añade en la función didMoveToView() :

```
self.view!.addGestureRecognizer(gestoDeslizar)
```

Esto añade el gesto a la escena.
Esto te debería dar la funcionalidad básica que puedes ir puliendo para adaptarlo a lo que quieras y necesites.

Comment: Ya debería estar